# InstanceStore WaitForEvents not firing when using WorkflowApplication with a WorkflowIdentity

Tags: c#, workflow

I posted this question on the microsoft forum but wanted to post it here for additional exposure. I have searched everywhere for an example of what I'm trying to do with no luck.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wfprerelease/thread/8a424c0b-44f8-4670-8d64-9c7142117b55

Basically, I would like to use the WorkflowApplication along with the WorkflowIdentity and persistence store to accomplish durable delays.  I use WorkflowApplication because we have hundreds of workflows that need to be run dynamically so the WorkflowServiceHost is not really feasible in our scenario.

I used the Microsoft provided example, AbsoluteDelay, as a starting point and it works perfectly.  The problem comes when I try to pass in a WorkflowIdentity to the constructor of the WorkflowApplication.

Then, the WaitForEvents event on the InstanceStore does not fire because it is expecting the default Identity (id 1), not my new Identity (id 2). The line that does store.Execute creates a record in the IdentityOwnerTable with SurrogateIdentityId set to 1 instead of the id of my identity.

How can I tell the InstanceStore to use my new Identity and not the default one? It seems as if it is something that can be passed through in the CreateWorkflowOwnerCommand metadata.

```
// Create the InstanceStore
SqlWorkflowInstanceStore store = new SqlWorkflowInstanceStore(_workflowDB);

// A well known property that is needed by WorkflowApplication and the InstanceStore
private static readonly XName _workflowHostTypePropertyName = XNamespace.Get("urn:schemas-microsoft-com:System.Activities/4.0/properties").GetName("WorkflowHostType");

// Create the XName for the workflow using the workflow's unique name
XName wfHostTypeName = XName.Get(workflowName);

// Configure a Default Owner for the instance store so instances can be re-loaded from WorkflowApplication
private static InstanceHandle CreateInstanceStoreOwner(InstanceStore store, XName wfHostTypeName)
{
    InstanceHandle ownerHandle = store.CreateInstanceHandle();
    CreateWorkflowOwnerWithIdentityCommand ownerCommand = new CreateWorkflowOwnerWithIdentityCommand()
    { //changed from CreateWorkflowOwnerCommand (did not fix problem)
        InstanceOwnerMetadata =
        {
            { _workflowHostTypePropertyName, new InstanceValue(wfHostTypeName) },
            // Something here to identify the WorkflowIdentity ??
        }
    };
    store.DefaultInstanceOwner = store.Execute(ownerHandle, ownerCommand, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)).InstanceOwner;
    return ownerHandle;
}

private static void WaitForRunnableInstance(InstanceStore store, InstanceHandle ownerHandle)
{
    // Only fires when using default Identity
    IEnumerable<InstancePersistenceEvent> events = store.WaitForEvents(ownerHandle, TimeSpan.MaxValue);
    bool foundRunnable = false;
    // Loop through the persistence events looking for the HasRunnableWorkflow event (in this sample, it corresponds with
    // the workflow instance whose timer has expired and is ready to be resumed by the host). 
    foreach (InstancePersistenceEvent persistenceEvent in events)
    {
         if (persistenceEvent.Equals(HasRunnableWorkflowEvent.Value))
         {
             foundRunnable = true;
             break;
         }
    }
    if (!foundRunnable)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("Unexpected: No runnable instances found in the instance store");
     }
}
```